# Is possible to have a Spiral formation for oceanic dorsal or tectonic plates borders?

Tags: planets, mountains

Is it possible in a world to have for example spiral-like formations of mountains or oceanic dorsal?

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely.

In a flat plane convective cells would tend to arrange themselves in an hexagonal pattern. It can be visualized by putting oil between two transparent plates and uniformly heating the bottom one.

In a sphere things are a bit more complicated but nevertheless there would need to be a rising zone and a sinking zone around a convective cell.

A spiral would need something to actively twist the flow while not disturbing the cell.